# Independant Password protection or access of php code and MySql db in cPanel

Tags: mysql, laravel, cpanel

Not sure this is an appropriate question because not writing any code.

A Laravel 8.x application hosted in a shared hosting.

As a developer I do not wish to allow client to access my script for copy or download or tampering it. While obfuscation of the code is a severe inconvenience for modifications and bug clearance and so does encryption and decryption at run time.

Many clients are not ready for cloud hosting as SaaS model (eg in India) for the fear of access to their data. As a client they do not wish me to have any access to the data in MySQL DB (for example using phpMyAdmin in cPanel I can't open and see any of its contents).

Is this envisioned by any? Is it possible to have two different passwords for each?

Comment: "Is it possible to have two different passwords for each" - whatever "for each" means, that should be possible

Comment: If you have access the code and the code has access to the username and password for mysql in plain text (as this is how mysql clients submit these), then you can have access to these as well.

Comment: In principle yes, the question is to infuse some confidence to the SAAS user. Question is closed and I do not have complaint on it.

Comment: There is a security sister site of SO where you can ask questions about IT security related matters as the database protection for SAAS tenants is more in their domain from an approach point of view. Once you have the approach and you get stuck with the implementation, you can come back here.